# Login with Google redairecting on conformation page to continue Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth, google-authenticator

I am trying to integrate Google Authentication into my login page. I am working in Django. I have added login with Google Button on my login page, but when I click on that button, I am redirecting to accounts/google/login where it's asking for conformation to continue and menu with sign-in and sign-out.

But what I want is when I click on the button it should ask for accounts to login instead.

This is my login screen:
[image]

This is what I get on click on the button:
[image]

this is my button login code in HTML:
Login.html:

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Welcome, You are logged in as {{ user.username }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}">Login With Google</a>
    {% endif %}
```

How can I skip this conformation page , it will be glad if anyone can help me out with this thank you.

Comment: you should check this https://dev.to/mdrhmn/django-google-authentication-using-django-allauth-18f8

Comment: I have used this and cloned project mentioned in this blog you have shared, but still, I am getting the same page, Here also.
I have made changes in my project according to this blog but nothing changed, still getting this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior was released in [version 0.47.0:](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes.html#section-3)

> Added a new setting SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET that controls whether or not the endpoints for initiating a social login (for example, “/accounts/google/login/”) require a POST request to initiate the handshake. As requiring a POST is more secure, the default of this new setting is False.

You can add the flag in your settings.py file to avoid the intermediate page:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True
```

And keep using the latest version of the library.

Answer (score 1):

I have uninstalled Django-allauth using the following command :

```
pip uninstall django-allauth
```

After that I have installed an older version of that using:

```
pip install django-allauth==0.45
```

Then:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
pytthon manage.py migrate
```

Done.