# Django All Auth Google Login Prevent extra page

Tags: django

I have enabled google login in my Django web application. right now what happens is, when i click on login the url is as follows:  it takes me to this page (please find the image below) which i want to prevent but can't figure out how do i.
[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq59g.jpg)

Please assist.

Comment: please provide  some more information such as your code, error messages (if any) so that we can provide help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question has already been answered in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873098/login-with-google-redairecting-on-conformation-page-to-continue-django?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uninstalled Django-allauth using the following command :

```
pip uninstall django-allauth
```

After that I have installed an older version of that using:

```
pip install django-allauth==0.45
```

Then:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
pytthon manage.py migrate
```

Done. This solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

This behavior was released in [version 0.47.0:](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes.html#section-3)

> Added a new setting SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET that controls whether or not the endpoints for initiating a social login (for example, “/accounts/google/login/”) require a POST request to initiate the handshake. As requiring a POST is more secure, the default of this new setting is False.

You can add the flag in your settings.py file to avoid the intermediate page:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True
```

And keep using the latest version of the library.

Answer (score -1):

simply add the following code to your settings.py file

```
# This line escapes the intermediate page
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True
```